# Problem formatting long dates and using GetLocaleInfoEx with LOCALE_SLONGDATE

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am getting confused here. According to my Windows 10 Regional Settings the Long Date format is:

[image]

I was adjusting some MFC code:

```
strDate = CFormatUtility::FormatAsLongDate(datToFormat);
```

So the above calls this method:

```
CString CFormatUtility::FormatAsLongDate(COleDateTime datDate)
{
    CString strFormattedText;

    TRY
    {
        TCHAR szDateFormatString[_MAX_PATH];
        GetLocaleInfoEx(theApp.GetHtmlLanguageCode(),
            LOCALE_SLONGDATE, szDateFormatString, _MAX_PATH);

        strFormattedText = FormatAsCustomDate(datDate, szDateFormatString);
    }
    CATCH(CException, Except)
    {

    }
    END_CATCH

    return strFormattedText;
}
```

I don't show you the subsequent method because the issue is here:

```
    TCHAR szDateFormatString[_MAX_PATH];
    GetLocaleInfoEx(theApp.GetHtmlLanguageCode(),
        LOCALE_SLONGDATE, szDateFormatString, _MAX_PATH);
```

According to the advanced Windows Settings:

[image]

Yet when I use the above code:

[image]

As you can see, the format string is `dddd, MMMM d, yyyy` which is not right.

According to the documentation for [`LOCALE_SLONGDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-slongdate) it says:

> Long date formatting string for the locale. The maximum number of characters allowed for this string is 80, including a terminating null character. The string can consist of a combination of day, month, year, and era format pictures and any string of characters enclosed in single quotes. Characters in single quotes remain as specified. For example, the Spanish (Spain) long date is "dddd, dd' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy". Locales can define multiple long date formats.

I should clarify that the value of the first parameter is `en`.

## Update

I see in my Regional settings that there are several types of long date:

[image]

But the whole point of this exercise is that I obtain the format string that is in use by the regional settings. And it is not returning that string `dd MMMM yyyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (in my case is that my operating system is English UK. So I had to use a language code of `en-gb` and then it shows my date format string.